# LINQ Generic IQueryable<T> WHERE Clause

Tags: linq, reflection, dbcontext

Let's say I have a DBContext with 3 DBSets:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

class C
{
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I want to write a **generic** method that:

1. Generically takes any of the three `DbSet` as the first argument
2. Takes a string value as the second argument
3. Without casting to `IEnumerable`, returns the first record in the provided `DbSet` where the `Code` field matches the provided string

So far I have this method:

```
public static T GetCode<T>(IQueryable<T> set, string code) where T : class
{
    var Prop = typeof(T).GetProperty("Code");
    return set.Where(x => (string)Prop.GetValue(x) == code).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When I try to call it using this line:

```
var _A = GetCode(TheDB.As, "123");
var _B = GetCode(TheDB.Bs, "123");
var _C = GetCode(TheDB.Cs, "123");
```

I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException:
>
> The LINQ expression 'DbSet<A>.Where(m => (string)__Prop_0.GetValue(m) == __code_1)' could not be translated.
>
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

How can I write the `WHERE` clause on the `DbSet` that is able to translate properly for `IQueryable`? My method works if I cast the `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable`, but I don't want to do that, since the set may potentially be very large and I want the database (not my application) to do the record searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest (and type safe) approach would be just to introduce an interface like `IHaveCode` and limit the generic parameter to it:

```
interface IHaveCode
{
     string Code { get; set; }
}

class A: IHaveCode
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

class B: IHaveCode
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

class C: IHaveCode
{
    public string Book { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public static T GetCode<T>(IQueryable<T> set, string code) where T : IHaveCode
{
    return set.Where(x => x.Code == code).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If for some reason it does not suit you then you will need to construct an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A more Generic method than the one from Guru Stron, one that is also usable for DbSets of classes without a property `Code`, would be to provide the property that you want to use in your comparison.

```
public static T GetFirstPropertyMatchOrDefault<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> propertySelector,
    string comparisonValue)
{
    return source.Where(sourceElement => propertySelector(sourceElement) == comparisonValue)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Usage:

```
string comparisonValue = ...
A fetchedA = dbContext.As.GetFirstPropertyMachOrDefault(a => a.Code, comparisonValue);
```

But now that you have made it generic, you can also use it to fetch other properties;

```
// Get a C by Book title:
string bookTitle = ...
C fetchedC = dbContext.Cs.GetFirstPropertyOrDefault(c => c.Book);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the GetCode method using [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).

```cs
public static T GetCode<T>(IQueryable<T> set, string code) where T : class {
    PropertyInfo codeProp = typeof(T).GetProperty("Code");
    if(codeProp == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(T).FullName} does not have the Code property");
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression getCode = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, codeProp);
    Expression codeVal = Expression.Constant(code);
    Expression body = Expression.Equal(getCode, codeVal);
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    return set.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```